# Use Node module export as constructor with new operator

Tags: node-modules

Why do I have to assign an exported constructor, before I can use it with the `new` operator to instantiate an object type?

For example (using npm package [rss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss)):

```
const feed1 = new require('rss'); // => errors out: this is undefined in constructor

const rss = require('rss'),
  feed2 = new rss; // => works fine
```

As far as I understand Node's module system, `require('rss')` exposes the constructor. So why can't I use it "directly"?

Comment: what do you get with `rss = new require("rss")()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens because you leave off the parentheses after the constructor. What internally happens is that node thinks of adding parentheses after the require() call – at least this is what it looks like:

```
const i = new require('rss') // results in an error
```

now, let's write it with parentheses instead:

```
const i = new require('rss')()
```

This does not work either, because in this case, node tries to evaluate `require('rss')()` first, and then executes `new`, because everything is evaluated from right to left.

Let's tell node now to not execute the rss exports, but instead properly create an instance:

```
const i = new (require('rss'))()
```

Comment: Ah! So, the premature resolution (respectively missing encapsulation) of the constructor reference is the problem. In my 2nd code example that premature resolution didn't happen, because the constructor reference is encapsulated in a variable.